# Issue with make in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I've been using cygwin to build gcc. However, after I try to configure gcc, in the way shown below:

```
$ C:/cygwin64/home/myusername/gcc-9.3.0/configure --program-suffix=-4.9.2 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-bootstrap --disable-shared
```

and then compile it like this:

```
$ make -j4
```

I have this error message:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I don't have much experience with cygwin, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: any specific reason to need an old compiler version ?

Comment: cd to `C:/cygwin64/home/myusername/gcc-9.3.0/`, then use `./configure`. Then make can pickup the Makefile from that directory.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else has this problem lately.. My error was extracting the file with the name of the folder So obviously the path wasn't correct because now was duplicated, just remove that one, select "extract here"

[image]

and now use the command. Otherwise, modify the path, that should work, too